# How to use the filepicker library in android studio?

Tags: android, github

I am new at android development. and I am creating a file choosing system.  I found one library on github.
the library is filepicker. [This is the link](https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker)

The I don't know how to import in android studio. can anybody tell me how should I start using this library. this file does not contains .jar file.

Comment: The first words in the project documentation are: "The project is no longer being maintained" and it is unlikely to work well on modern versions of Android. That being said, there is [an installation section](https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker#installation), [extensive usage notes](https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker#usage), and [a wiki with a bit more documentation](https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker/wiki).

Comment: `I am creating a file choosing system`. Not needed. Android has all to choose any file.

Comment: can u send me the documentation link or some reference how should i start developing file choosing feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multple sample code provided in Github for one to use.
For example `SimpleFileDialog`.

1. Go to [Android File Chooser Dialog](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/android-file-chooser-dialog/blob/master/src/com/scorchworks/demo/SimpleFileDialog.java)
2. Copy `SimpleFileDialog.java` to your android project.
3. Provide required permission in manifest.
4. use it inside your application as mentioned in the Github page.

   ```
   public void onButtonChooseFile(View v) {

       //Create FileOpenDialog and register a callback
       SimpleFileDialog fileOpenDialog =  new SimpleFileDialog(
           MainActivity.this, 
           "FileOpen..",
           new SimpleFileDialog.SimpleFileDialogListener() {
               @Override
               public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir) {
                   // The code in this function will be executed when the dialog OK 
                   //button is pushed
                   editFile.setText(chosenDir);
               }
           }
       );

       //You can change the default filename using the public variable 
       //"Default_File_Name"
       fileOpenDialog.default_file_name = editFile.getText().toString();
       fileOpenDialog.chooseFile_or_Dir(fileOpenDialog.default_file_name);
   }
   ```

Similar examples is [Android FileSelector](https://github.com/criss721/Android-FileSelector).

Comment: If you want to use android default file provider for both local and aexternal storage refer this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38170719/1994089